# How to break up a list of items to edit among multiple web users

Tags: asp.net, locking

I have an ASP.NET 4 application where I have a list of items and users need to do some work on each item. Since the list can be very long, I want this review process for each item to occur as efficiently as possible. My idea is to have a web page that displays one item, the user does what they need to do, then clicks on a Next Item button. The system automatically picks the next item from the list. So far so good...if only one user needs to do this.

The difficulty is in coming up with a reliable and effective solution for allowing multiple users to work through the list. If a user clicks Next, I don't want the system to bring up the same item that another user is working on.

It's not the end of the world if two users work on the same item (the last to save wins), but it's a waste of time and should be kept to a minimum.

Some techniques that I can think of:

1) Pick the next item randomly from the list. The chance of two users getting the same item goes way down. The bad is that users can't predict what they will get next and can't really work sequentially through the list.

2) Use some kind of optimistic locking to lock the record. This is generally bad for web applications since the user can go to any page or kill the connection, potentially leaving the lock there until some kind of expiration. The good part about this is that users can work through the list or parts of it sequentially and the system will simply skip records that somebody else is working on.

However, does anybody have any other suggestins?

**Update:**
Assuming that a user is only allowed to edit ONE record at a time (i.e. no opening other browser pages or sessions on the same list) one possible solution for using optimistic locking is as follows:

1. For each record, (as @Shai suggested) keep track of: Edit status (Available, InProgress), User currently editing, Date edit was started.
2. When a user wants to get the next record, lock the table, scan for the next Available record, change it's status to InProgress, unlock the table. Update the user and date information.
3. When a session expires (perhaps the user closed their browser), set any records associated with this user to Available. Sessions last a few hours in order to support extended editing timeframe.
4. If the same user logs on again before the other session is expired, again set any records associated to this user to Available.

Now, this is where it gets a bit complicated. What if the user goes home but didn't finish with a record (or a list of records, if we allow more than one), how do we get other users to be able to take over without waiting? We could add a special UI to list all current user sessions and allow somebody (who knows the user is no longer working) to explicitly unlock any records.

Any suggestions on improving this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the items should potentially have 3 statuses (statusi?): Open, InProgress and Completed. When the user requests an item you return the first item with a status of Open, and at the same time set that item's status to "InProgress". And when they save the item, you can set it's status to "Completed". Rinse. Repeat.

To make sure that no two users get the same open item, you can lock the table during a quick sproc that selects the open item and set's its status to "InProgress". This sproc can have the item id as it's return value. By only returning the id rather than the entire record, you will be locking the table for a shorter amount of time. Then you can select the actual record without worrying about another user retrieving ownership of the same record.

You might also want to consider recording the user who took ownership of the item. This might come in handy if you ever need to perform auditing.

Is this the direction you were going for?

Comment: Yes, this is the optimistic locking scenario. The complications arise if the user just exits their browser. That record then becomes unavailable (to anybody or even the same user) until somehow changed back to Open. I will update my original post with some ideas on this.

Comment: The only "lock" I meant to imply is the db one to select which item to assign to a user. Depending on business rules, once the item is assigned to a specific user, that user cannot take ownership of another item until the item is completed. I did not mean to imply that the entire item is "locked" rather it is "assigned".

Comment: Thanks @Shai, I understood what you meant. I am thinking of optimistic locking in the general (business rules) sense, not in the database-specific sense since we are dealing with a web site.